# Add to listBox in form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to add some text to a listBox in a form, from another form, but I get red underlines in the code that should add to the listBox. Isn't it possible to pass data to a form in a class from another class that I'm trying to do? I'm using VisualStudio 2010

I have this code I'm using in the MainForm class:

```
// Local object of SearchResultForm
SearchResultForm frmSearchResult = new SearchResultForm();
frmSearchResult.Show();
frmSearchResult.lstSearchResult.Items.Add("Test");
```

Error message: inaccessible due to its protected level

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: _What error do you get?_

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code snippet.  The error says that you didn't use `lstSearchResult`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A control is usually a variable, so try this for Winforms:

```
frmSearchResult.lstSearchResult.Add("Test");
```

WPF:

```
frmSearchResult.lstSearchResult.Items.Add("Test");
```

Comment: Not working, I get a red underline under lstSearchResult and a message about inaccessible due to its protected level!?

Comment: Then the control variable is created as `protected ListBox lstSearchResult`. You can change the modifies property of the control to public. Then you can access the control. Other than that, have you thought about creating a public method (`public void AddToListbox(string value)`) in which you add to the listbox?

Comment: Hmm, sorry but I new to this kind of things! How do I change the control variable to not be protected? I try to make a method

Comment: It's a property, when you're on the designer, the properties contains an entry for Modifiers. This is set to protected, and should be a dropdown containing also public. Personally I would opt for the method, as it is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2):

Confused, you are.

Assume the following:

- frmSearchResult - the name of the form
- myDDL - The `DropDownList` that is nested in the latter form

In order to add new items to the dropdown,

```
frmSearchResult.myDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem("New item!", "some-value"));
```

EDIT:

Create a new public method in `frmSearchResult` that allows you to add new items

```
public void addNewListItem(string sText, string sValue){
    myDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(sText, sValue));
}
```

And then call `addNewListItem` from the 1st form:

```
frmSearchResult.addNewListItem("New item!", "some-value");
```

Comment: Hmm, not working I get some error aboutinaccessible due to its protected level!? Why (new ListItem(.... ?

Comment: I go for the method alternative, but I don't se the point in using the new listItem in your code? Please explaint why, it works fine without! (new ListItem(sText, sValue));

Comment: `new ListItem()` contains an overload that lets you set the Value of the ListItem, it's up to your needs whether to use this overload or not, it's you who decide whether the Value of the ListItem is crucial for your application or not (-: